# Add a column to a view with the value form X days ago

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to combine two (or more) tables in a view and add one column to the resulting table that represents the value of Column 3 from X days ago (in the picture 2 days ago).

I have added an image with an example layout and my expected layout.
[image]

The two tables have a different date frequency (one every 12 hours and the other every day). When no values are found on that time, a NULL values is places in the table.

This is the query so far:

```
SELECT 
    T4.Date,
    MAX(T4.COL1) as COL1,
    MAX(T4.COL2) as COL2,
    MAX(T4.COL3) as COL3,
    MAX(T3.COL4) as COL4
FROM (
    SELECT T1.Date as Date, T1.COL1 as COL1, T1.COL2 as COL2, null as COL3
    FROM [TABLE 1] as T1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T2.Date as Date, null as COL1, null as COL2, T2.COL3 as COL3
    FROM [TABLE 1] as T2

) T4

OUTER APPLY (SELECT COL3 as COL4
            FROM [TABLE 2]
            WHERE Date IN (
                SELECT MAX(Date) FROM [Table 2]
                WHERE
                Date <= DATEADD(dd, -2, T1.Date)
            )) T3

GROUP BY T1.Date
-- The order by will be left out of the View for performance
ORDER BY T1.Date
```

The resulting table looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that the `COL4` values are all filed in but I expect the to be `null` when there is no value for `COL3`.
I know that the problem is that the values for `COL4` are looked up in [Table 2] instead of the table [T4] but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: why the thumb down on this when he has shown his own efforts, data, and results?

Comment: @Cato Probably because the solution was a bit easy looking at it now and it wasn't worth asking the question. but I'm not here for the points, I just want to finish the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change on :

```
CASE WHEN MAX(T4.COL3) IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE MAX(T3.COL4) END AS COL4
```

OR

```
CASE WHEN COL3 IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE MAX(T3.COL4) END AS COL4
```

Comment: This solution works and I will mark it as answered but in the meantime I found another possibility for my case: changing `Date <= DATEADD(dd, -2, T1.Date)` to
`Date = DATEADD(dd, -2, T1.Date)` gave me the same result.

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I m glad that I could help :) Have a nice day ! @lordvlad30